# How can I debug an angular.dart template?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have some angular components that sometimes don't correctly initialize.  I'll see curly-brackets in the output and event handlers aren't working.  It's not the entire app, just pieces of it.

I don't get any uncaught exceptions.

Is there any way to turn a debug-mode on to find out what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like Batarang but that is not yet available for Dart.

What I usually do is putting a print/log statement in the constructor.

Most of the time the problem is a typo in the selector or a type not registered in the module.
When the constructor of a type doesn't print I know there is something wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's a typo issue, everything works most of the time.  The constructors do get called and there are no exceptions in the code I've written (stepped through every method).

Comment: It's cumbersome but what I often do is change fields to getters and setters and make log output in the implementation so that I see if and when they are accessed and what values are returned/set.